# javaでMySQLにあるテーブルを検索してなければ新規テーブルを作成したい。

Tags: java, jdbc

「車票」というテーブルがデータベース内に存在しない場合、新規に作成して中身を表示するプログラムを作成したいです。

現在のプログラムでは、エラーで`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'cardb.車票' doesn't exist`と出てしまいます。改善方法を教えていただきたいです。

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Sample1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/cardb";
        String user = "***";
        String pw = "****";

        Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pw);

        DatabaseMetaData dm = cn.getMetaData();
        ResultSet tb = dm.getTables(null, null, "車票", null);

        Statement st = cn.createStatement();

        String qry1 = "CREATE TABLE 車票(番号 int, 名前 varchar(50))";
        String[] qry2 = {
                "INSERT INTO 車票 VALUES (2, '乗用車')",
                "INSERT INTO 車票 VALUES (3, 'オープンカー')",
                "INSERT INTO 車票 VALUES (4, 'トラック')"};
        String qry3 = "SELECT * FROM 車票";

        if(!tb.next()) {
            st.executeUpdate(qry1);
            for(int i=0; i<qry2.length; i++) {
                st.executeUpdate(qry2[i]);
            }
        }

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(qry3);

        ResultSetMetaData rm = rs.getMetaData();
        int cnum = rm.getColumnCount();
        while(rs.next()) {
            for(int i=1; i<=cnum; i++) {
                System.out.print(rm.getColumnName(i) +":"+  rs.getObject(i) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        rs.close();
        st.close();
        cn.close();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 私の環境では動作しますね。具体的にどの部分でどのエラーが発生するのでしょうか？（エラー全文を貼り付けても良いかと思います）

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。以下エラー内容です  
 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'cardb.車票' doesn't exist
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1218)
 at Sample1.main(Sample1.java:34)

Comment: 日本語のテーブル名が問題かもしれません。車票ではなくcar_ticket などにして実行したらどうなりますか？　（日本語などのマルチバイト文字のテーブル名やカラム名は推奨しません）

Comment: かなり昔のものですが [Table doesn't exist after CREATE TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142002/table-doesnt-exist-after-create-table)でも同じ事象についての質問がありますね(upvote 2桁あるので、その人の環境だけに発生している事象というわけでもなさそう)。ワークアラウンドは見つかったものの、原因は不明のままのようです。また、Java/JDBCではないので、MySQL自身の話なのでしょうかね(MySQLのissueを探すと他の情報も得られるかも？)。